# Retrieve PHP Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, ajax

I am trying to get a PHP array variable and save it in Javascript. The following is what I have now.

**array.php**

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
echo json_encode($cars);
```

**jsarray.php**

```
var temp_array = new Array();
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "array.php",
      cache: false,
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
          temp_array=data;
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
      }

   });
```

I can't get value of the PHP array.

How do I fix this problem?

Edit: console.log(temp_array) only returns a [  ]

Edit 2: added "error" and console.log(textStatus, errorThrown).

**Error Message**

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
return window.JSON.parse( data + "" );
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't get the value of the PHP array? Do you get any errors? An array has multiple values, or are you saying that the `success` callback does not fire?

Comment: rather than write echo put return json_encode($cars);exit(); and try

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't get value of the PHP Array"? Is the result of your ajax call null? Are you getting errors? What are you seeing as output if you console.log temp_array

Comment: @muglio the output for console.log is `[  ]`

Comment: @ExplosionPills no error is shown and output for console.log on temp_array returns `[  ]`

Comment: @plasticbullet Should have asked about data. Are you seeing something in data or is it also empty/null?

Comment: @muglio not sure what i am doing wrong, but when i try to log data, it is not showing anything. I've added `console.log(data)` right after `temp_array=data`

Comment: Sorry for all the back and forth just trying to catch up where you are in debugging process. Have you tried opening up array.php in your browser? I assume that both of these things are also running in the same domain.

Comment: @muglio yes i've tried that. array seems to be in order over in the php file.

Comment: @PeeHaa question edited

Comment: @Charles question edited.

Comment: @Machavity question edited.

Comment: @tereško question edited.

Comment: Run jsarray.php this in chrome, right click, Inspect Element, Click Network Tab, Reload the page, Click XHR, You should see your call to array.php coming through. If the status is ok, select Headers tab and verify you are getting a content-type back of application/javascript and that you don't have any erroneous stuff under the response tab

Comment: @muglio I do see the array that I wanted in the header tab which is in the following format `["Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota"]` but still unable to get this array in the js file. `success` doesn't seems to fire at all.

Comment: Do you have this on a server somewhere? If you are able to share a URL for  jsarray.php and array.php I'll dig into a bit and see if what the heck is going on.

Comment: Hi plasticbullet, I alert the data as "alert(data)" the php value is coming. Then what problem you facing?

Answer (score 0):

You JSON encode the array server-side, but you never decode it back to an array client-side. [This](http://www.thecave.info/pass-a-php-array-to-javascript-as-json-using-ajax-and-json_encode/) might help.

Comment: shouldn't the `dataType: 'json',` handle that for us already? please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I could be wrong, but I thought `data` would still contain the json.  Try printing the value of data to see what you get.  Or you could scrap that method and copy the way the example does it.  It's fairly easy to implement

Answer (score 0):

your php script must send the right http headers to tell it is sending json content, like this (before echoing ) :

```
$cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($cars);
```

Comment: I've added those line of code but still not getting it.